# jQuery each() only hits first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to loop through some elements and delete their parent div holder if it is found to be empty. I am using the following jquery code and for some reason, it only removes the first matched element and none after this.

```
$('.sylsection p').each( function() {
  if ( $(this).text() == '' ) {
  $(this).closest('.sylsection').remove();
  }
});
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

HTML structure is something like:

```
<div class="sylsection">
  <h6>Content</h6>
  <hr>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>

<div class="sylsection">
  <h6></h6>
  <hr>
  <p></p>
</div>

<div class="sylsection">
  <h6>Content</h6>
  <hr>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>

<div class="sylsection">
  <h6></h6>
  <hr>
  <p></p>
</div>

<div class="sylsection">
  <h6>Content</h6>
  <hr>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>

<div class="sylsection">
  <h6></h6>
  <hr>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Don't mind the in html markup. Will move that to an external css file later.

Cheers

Comment: Attach the .each() function to sylsection class only, .each() allows you to iterate only siblings elements

Comment: Hi @korwalskiy I am unfortunately still running into the same problem. It just seems to bail out after the first one. Initialy I thought it had to do with the .remove() function, so tried .css('display', 'none') and.hide() but that did not work either.

Comment: This is what I implied:
$('.sylsection').each(function () {
  if ($(this).children('p').text() == '') {
     $(this).remove();
  }
});

Comment: Is this the `actual` HTML output? The only reason I ask is if any of the `<p>` elements contain at least one space, then the string wouldn't be empty. Does it work properly if you trim the text in your comparison (i.e. `if($(this).text().trim() == '')`)?

Comment: @korwalskiy It still limits itself to the first one, unfortunately.

Comment: @mark.hch Yes, all p elements are completely empty. The actual html output does contain in HTML style markup but that cannot be it can it? Both, thanks for your input.

Comment: @mark.hch So I checked the original file again and noticed that some </p> elements where put one line lower. When I checked in the resulting webpage it said it was empty but after having put it on the same line in now works. My bad for not seeing this earlier. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine:

```js
  $('.sylsection p').each(function () {
      if ($(this).text() == '') {
          $(this).closest('.sylsection').remove();
      }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sylsection">
    <h6>Content 01</h6>
    <hr>
    <p>Content 02</p>
</div>

<div class="sylsection">
    <h6>Header 01</h6>
    <hr>
    <p></p>
</div>

<div class="sylsection">
    <h6>Content 03</h6>
    <hr>
    <p>Content 04</p>
</div>

<div class="sylsection">
    <h6>Header 02</h6>
    <hr>
    <p></p>
</div>

<div class="sylsection">
    <h6>Content 05</h6>
    <hr>
    <p>Content 06</p>
</div>

<div class="sylsection">
    <h6>Header 03</h6>
    <hr>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: You are absolutely right. Based on the comment from @marl.hch, I took another look at the original html code and saw that some </p> were put a line lower than the <p>. Even though the <p> showed to be empty on the website, it wasn't recognized as such. Now it is fixed, and the code runs fine. Thank you all for your input.

Comment: You're welcome. You could also check for  a `<p>`'s content with `if ((this).innerText == '')` (ignores any whitespace) - vanilla js, no jquery needed.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to execute the code with jQuery 1.12.4 (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js) and it seems to work properly, see this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0Lbp8xL1/3/

The function and the html is the same:

```
$('.sylsection p').each( function() {
    if ( $(this).text() == '' ) {
        $(this).closest('.sylsection').remove();
  }
});
```

Comment: Apparently we wrote it at the same time, you have inserted the answer while I was writing mine (and trying on JSFiddle) ... look at the time...